# After clicking, value of input field is incorrect on a different computer

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my computer lets say an input field is to be submitted, a user clicks the submit button and sends the value of that input field to display the next window. If the input is correct like "gold", it will pop open a window. If its incorrect, it won't pop up.  On my computer the window pops up when I type in "gold", but on my friend's computer he types exactly the same "gold" in and the window doesn't pop up for him. Whats wrong? Is it a cache/history issue?

Here is my code just in case:

```
function LFD_SearchContainer (requestedContainer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let lfd_scanparams = { TableName: 'lfd_table1' }
        db.scan(lfd_scanparams, (err, containers) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                containers = containers.Items;

                let requestedContainers = []; // different variable than arg - has an extra "s"

                let containerObject; // this will be the resolved object

                // this will make containerObject the container object of the searched container if match is found
                let findIt = _.forEach(containers, container => {
                    if (container.container === requestedContainer) {
                        containerObject = container;
                    }
                });
                if (!findIt) {
                    reject();
                } else {
                    containerObject = findIt[0];
                    resolve(containerObject);
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
} 

// container number LFD column
$(function() {
    $("#lfdsubmit").click(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let lfd_containerfield = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val(); // input field


        console.log(lfd_containerfield);
        LFD_SearchContainer(lfd_containerfield)
        .then(containerObject => { // object returned of matched container
            ST2.db2(containerObject.terminal, containerObject); // will send the object of matched container down to STEP 2 (database of TERMINALS)
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Is your friend using an ES6 compatible browser?

Comment: maybe your friend has disabled javascript on his browser or popups.  Or he is using a different version of the browser that does not support it.

Comment: please post the different browsers (name & version)

Comment: I don't know if his browser is compatible but we have 3 other input values that should pop up a window for him but they work for him, its just the value "gold". It works for me but not for him. Weird issue

Comment: Do you get an error in Console? Firebug? Has he cleared cache? Have you tried other machines? Browsers?